# Getting the index of a float number in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I've executed this code, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
A = 1:0.1:1.4

A =

    1.0000    1.1000    1.2000    1.3000    1.4000

A == 1.3000

ans =

    0     0     0     0     0
```

I thought I was going to get:

```
    ans =

        0     0     0     1     0
```

Why does it not work? And how can I make it work as I want?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read a useful article on [Floating Point Comparisons in Matlab](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/floating-point-comparisons-in-matlab/)

Comment: And: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the usual when you compare floats. Try `A(4)-1.3`. It'll give you something small but not zero. That's because floats have finite precision. In general, it's better not to test for equality with floats.

The usual approach is to define a small tolerance (for example `1e-9`) and compare taking that tolerance into account:

```
abs(A-1.3)<1e-9
```

Comment: Practical tip: If you often work within the same range of numbers (like me) you can define a function called `epsilon` or `eps` for example and make sure it is always on your path. The only thing the function does is return something like `1e-9` and it allows you to comfortably and consistently do these kind of comparisons. Also help s if you try to find places where you made floating point comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

0.1 has an infinite expansion when written in base 2:
0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100

shell code to obtain that:

```
bc -lq
obase=2
1/10
```

Matlab will truncate to 50(?) digits. Because of this, 0.1*3 and 0.3 are different.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of double precision. Try `format long g` and have a look at A again, you'll see that it's not exactly 1.3. Have a look at the [MATLAB wiki](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F) to understand why that is. It's never a good idea to do an equality test on a floating point number.